# PSQL: error: relation does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I am getting an Error when I do a get request with Express from my database and I am not sure what it means. Here is a short form of the error:

{ error: relation "movies" does not exist
    at Connection.parseE

Here is my code (server.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var knex = require("./db/knex");
var movies = require('./routes/movies.js');
var actors = require('./routes/actors.js');
var roles = require('./routes/roles.js');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// router
// get all
app.get("/movies", movies.getAllMovies);

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Now listening on port " + port);
});
```

Module (movies.js):

```
var knex = require("../db/knex");

// get all
var getAllMovies = function(req, res) {
  knex.raw('SELECT * FROM movies')
  .then(function(movies) {
    res.send(movies.rows);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}

module.exports = {
   getAllMovies:getAllMovies,
   getOneMovie:getOneMovie,
   postMovie:postMovie,
   putMovie:putMovie,
   deleteMovie:deleteMovie
 }
```

Please let me know if you can find the error!

Comment: You don't have a table called `movies` in your database it seems?

Answer (score 2):

I actually figured it out. All the variables and tables were fine, but one of my knex configuration files was not connected to the correct database.

Original:

```
module.exports = {
      development: {
          client: 'pg',
          connection: 'postgres://localhost/stores', // ** WRONG **
          migrations: {
              directory: __dirname + '/db/migrations',
            },
          seeds: {
              directory: __dirname + '/db/seeds',
            },
        },
 }
```

Line 4 should have read:

```
connection: 'postgres://localhost/movies_and_actors'
```